# How to fix "FirebaseError: Expected type 'Query', but it was: a custom Firestore object"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a query which searches through my posts collection to retrieve a doc where the slug field is equal to the one found in the url. (Eg. "http://localhost:3000/jeff235/random-post-2" will find the doc with a slug field value of "random-post-2".) However I'm getting an error :

> FirebaseError: Expected type 'Query', but it was: a custom Firestore object

I've tried looking through other questions but none seem to help me? Here is my code for the page where I retrieve the doc and which has the error :

```
import styles from '../../styles/Post.module.css';
import PostContent from '../../components/PostContent';
import { firestore, getUserWithUsername, postToJSON } from '../../lib/firebase';
import { useDocumentData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
import { getDocs, query } from 'firebase/firestore'

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { username, slug } = params;
  const userDoc = await getUserWithUsername(username);

  let post;
  let path;

  if (userDoc) {
    const postRefQuery = query(
      collection(firestore, 'posts'),
      limit(1),
      where('slug', "==", slug)
    );
    const postRef = postToJSON(await getDocs(postRefQuery).docs[0]);
    path = postRef.path;
  }

  return {
    props: { post, path },
    revalidate: 5000,
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const snapshot = await getDocs(firestore, 'posts');

  const paths = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    const { slug, username } = doc.data();
    return {
      params : { slug, username },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem likely comes from here:

```
const snapshot = await getDocs(firestore, 'posts');
```

The `getDoc` function accepts either a `Query` or a `CollectionReference`, but you're passing it your `firestore` object.

This is more likely what you want:

```
const snapshot = await getDocs(collection(firestore, 'posts'));
```

Comment: I was getting other errors because  it seems like I was passing more than one doc into postToJSON so i change my code for it to look like this                                                   
   `const postRef = await getDoc(collection(userDoc.ref, 'posts').doc(slug)); post = postToJSON(await getDoc(postRef));` except now I'm given this error : "TypeError: (0 , firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.collection)(...).doc is not a function". Any ideas?